# "undefined value, reference not allowed" workaround

Tags: purescript

I'm looking for some clarification on the compiler error message `The value of xyz is undefined here, so reference is not allowed.`, together with the do-notation. I did not manage to generalize the example enough, all I can give is the concrete example where I stumbled upon this behaviour. Sorry for that.

Using [purescript-parsing](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-parsing/0.7.1), I want to write a parser which accepts nested multiline-comments. To simplify the example, each comment starts with `(`, ends with `)` and can contain either an `a`, or another comment. Some examples: `(a)` and `((a))` accepted, `()`, `(a` or `foo` get rejected.

The following code results in the error `The value of comment is undefined here, so reference is not allowed.` on the line `content <- string "a" <|> comment`:

```
comment :: Parser String String
comment = do
  open <- string "("
  content <- commentContent
  close <- string ")"
  return $ open ++ content ++ close

commentContent :: Parser String String
commentContent = do
  content <- string "a" <|> comment
  return content
```

I can get rid of the error by inserting a line above `content <- string "a" <|> comment` which as far as I understand it does not change the resulting parser at all:

```
commentContent :: Parser String String
commentContent = do
  optional (fail "")
  content <- string "a" <|> comment
  return content
```

The questions are:

- What is happening here? Why does the extra line help?
- What is a non-hacky way to get the code to compile?

Comment: Have you read the wiki page for the error code you are encountering, and this link? https://github.com/Thimoteus/SandScript/wiki/2.-Parsing-recursively - that the extra line fixes your problem is really strange, though.

Comment: Thanks, the sandscript texts were an interesting read. As for the error: I can see why it is needed, I just don't get why the extra line removes it. And the parser with the extra line does work as intented.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason the second case works becomes more apparent if you desugar the `do` manually:

```
commentContent :: Parser String String
commentContent =
  optional (fail "") >>= \_ ->
    string "a" <|> comment >>= \content ->
      return content
```

When defined this way, the `comment` reference is inside a lambda, so therefore is not evaluated during the definition of `commentContent`.

As for the non-hacky solution, it would involve some use of `fix` I imagine. `fix` allows you to define recursive parsers like:

```
myParser = fix \p -> do
   ... parser definition ....
```

Where `p` is a reference to `myParser` that you can use within itself. As for the case here where you have mutually recursive parsers, I'm not exactly sure how best to solve it with `fix`, there are a few options I can think of, but none are particularly elegant. Perhaps something like this:

```
parens :: Parser String String -> Parser String String
parens p = do
  open <- string "("
  content <- p
  close <- string ")"
  return $ open ++ content ++ close

comment :: Parser String String
comment = parens commentContent

commentContent :: Parser String String
commentContent = fix \p -> do
  content <- string "a" <|> parens p
  return content
```

It might be easier to use a trick similar to the strange `do` case and insert a `Unit ->` in front of one of the parsers, so you can delay the recursive reference until the `Unit` value is provided, something like:

```
comment :: Parser String String
comment = do
  open <- string "("
  content <- commentContent unit
  close <- string ")"
  return $ open ++ content ++ close

commentContent :: Unit -> Parser String String
commentContent _ = do
  content <- string "a" <|> comment
  return content
```